# Is the a way to use Dax Sameperiodlastyear Function to add sales from the 1st of the month to date?

Tags: powerbi, dax

`Hello, i have two financial year sales, now i want to see what was the sales total of last year same period, e.g today its april 26 my sales will only be on the 25th of april, now when i want to see what was sales april last same day using dax power bi.

I tried the following code but it's adding the next day which is 26 but i want 25th april.
`TTV Prior Year =

CALCULATE(
[TTV_Sales],
CALCULATETABLE(SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Final Calendar'[Date]),
'Final Calendar'[FutureDate] ="Past"))`

So what i want is if the total from 1st of april to 25th is 5,what was the sales on the same day previous year same month`

Comment: Hi, i managed to calculate it, thanks